# CDI Like Events in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, events, cdi

I am primarily a JEE6 developer. I did like to know if there is a way to implement Fire and forget functionality of CDI events in asp.net. and the event observers get to receive a specific data payload with which to respond to the event

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you'd have to have a registration object always available so your listeners can register thir interest.  Then that same object will have a fire method, or an event object would call that fire method, then you just iterate through the listeners and call their method. Use interfaces to keep it simple.